# why is wlanapi.lib missing on Windows XP SP3

Tags: winapi, network-programming

To get information about the wireless LAN cards, I came across the api **WlanEnumInterfaces** . In the documentation, it says

```
 Minimum supported client  - Windows Vista, Windows XP with SP3
```

It means that the api is available on the above mentioned Operating System

The application is running on Windows XP with SP3, but when inlcude  , it gives error - file not found.

If I search my whole PC, this file is not found. Even the corresponding library is 'wlanapi.lib' is missing

Any help would be useful...

Answer (score 3):

This import library is included with the Windows SDK.  I have to guess that you've got an old version of it on your machine.  The default install location is `c:\program files\microsoft\sdks\windows\???\lib` where `???` is the SDK version number (like v7.0).

You can [download the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) from Microsoft.  Do make sure that the version you get is compatible with your version of Visual Studio.  Do not attempt if you have an old one, like version 6.

Comment: When i do a windows search for the whole 'C:\' drive, the lib is not reported. But when I go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows' the following directories are listed: v5.0, v6.0A. The files found were :     
wlanapi.h 
and wlnapi.lib (2 versions , one in x64 dir).
 Can I now use this with my App, which is built using VS 6.0

Comment: You are using a compiler from the previous century, I have no idea.  Looks to me that you've got VS2008 as well, why don't you use it?

Comment: No, VC6 can't use any .lib files newer than the Feb 2003 SDK.  Which means no libs for Vista or Win7, period.

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking for `wlanapi.dll`, which is the runtime component.

Generally when you're using new APIs, you should be using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, so you can handle failure gracefully.

Comment: wlnapi.dll is not found. But wlnapi.lib is present when I go to the actual physical location 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows'.

Comment: @Ginu: Check your spelling, it's `wlanapi.dll` with two `a`s.  But since some computers will not have `wlanapi.dll`, you should test for it using `LoadLibrary`.  A load-time dependency, which linking with `wlanapi.lib` gives you, will cause your application to crash with no chance of recovery.  Don't use `wlanapi.lib`.  Do use `LoadLibrary`, and display an appropriate message when the DLL or its functions aren't available.